# In the output the denominator appears in front of the fraction

Tags: fractions, displaystyle

Command `\frac` works in strange way:

[image]

Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setlength{\textheight}{24.4cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\frac{1}{2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit your question so that it includes a complete example code that reproduces this behaviour.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As this is not the default behavior, we really need more information, so can you create a complete, minimal code example, a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), demonstrating the issue?

Comment: I added preambula of tex to my question. Both Tex => PDF and Tex=>DVI works same way.

Comment: Did you see that for you example there are errors in the log? `\frac` is a math mode command so you are seeing 'error recovery': `$\frac{1}{2}$` is correct for input and gives the right result.

Comment: Compiling your code produces several errors, because `\frac` is only valid in math mode (e.g. within `$...$`). You shouldn't expect the output document to look right if you get compilation errors.